# Triage Audit Failure by Marking as Duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, disputed-review-audits, triage

I just failed an audit within Triage because I flagged a question as a duplicate.  I was told that I failed because it was an answerable question.

This was the question used in the audit:  https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8757174 / ([How to join 2 lists of dicts in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746584/how-to-join-2-lists-of-dicts-in-python))

I marked it as duplicate against this Q/A, which has a great & extremely detailed answer:  [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

I probably should have looked at the question and seen that it was answered with an accepted answer already, however the question that I used as the canonical was answered a year earlier than the question used in the triage audit.  Did I do the wrong thing in this case, or was the audit not accurate?  If I did do the wrong thing, why would this not be considered a duplicate question?

Comment: I would say they are different but I don't know python.

Comment: Dups break all audits. That said, this doesn't look like a dup?

Comment: I think both of you two are correct.  I misunderstood the question being asked since I'm not a Python expert.  I probably should have just skipped this review.

Answer (score 15):

There are two things here:

- The question itself is one of those wonderfully misleading, "This looks low quality but it actually isn't" sorts of questions.  Getting that on an audit is never fun, and never straightforward to deal with.
- The duplicate you attempted to link to isn't a duplicate at all, as the dupe deals with two distinct dictionaries, but not a list of dictionaries.  There's a slight twist there.

Personally I wouldn't want this question as an audit question, since it's so easy to mistake it (I wonder why?), but there's not much you could do about this scenario.  If you know Python and you feel that it's an answerable question, go with that instinct; otherwise, don't feel afraid to skip the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I know a little bit of python, but not nearly enough to confidently answer python questions on SO.  I probably should have just skipped it.

Answer (score 15):

To the advice you've already gotten, I would add a further point: flagging dupes in Triage, at present, is something of a fool's errand, since nine times out of ten not enough other reviewers will consider the possibility of dupes or agree that it is one, and your flag will be disputed within minutes. Only flag dupe if you're sure that it will be obvious to most reviewers that a dupe is a possibility. (Or if someone else already correctly flagged as dupe, of course.) Instead, hit <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> and either open the post in a new tab to flag separately, or hope someone else does it.

The fact that this handily avoids some of the trickiest Triage audits is just a nice little bonus.

Comment: Nathan, is hitting `Looks Ok` really the right thing to do if you're going to flag it, seems like `Skip` would be the appropriate thing to do? Otherwise good info on flagging dupes from Triage, a lesson I had yet to learn.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ: These days I'd argue for Requires Editing instead, which doesn't dispute (other) dupe flags raised in Triage. But Triage is designed to finish *fast*, almost certainly before CV can handle the dupe, so simply Skipping doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: Agreed, my point was more or less that hitting `Looks Ok` would not be the appropriate action. `Requires Editing` definitely seems like the better approach.

Comment: Yes, it's almost as if the Triage queue was a sinister plot to make it hard to quickly close craps new questions, while *appearing* to be a means of increasing question quality.

Comment: @Raedwald: Never assume malice when incompetence will do. (Also, dupes are by no means the most common sort of terrible new question, so if Triage makes them a little harder in exchange for making others rather easier, that would be a fair trade.)