# Correct Duplicate Flag in Triage Marked Wrong

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, disputed-review-audits, triage

I recently did this review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11759089, where I marked the question as a duplicate of the thing that it had been closed for in the first place. However, the system responded with "Stop! Look and listen...". This seems like the wrong thing to do.

According to this [related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299008/2988730), questions that are answerable should be marked correct or skipped. However, in that case, [why is there an option to mark as duplicate at all in triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300723/2988730)? And why is is not tied to the audit functionality correctly?

Comment: Maybe we should create a review queue for the review queue:-). Looking at the duplicate question, you basically shouldn't flag a question as a duplicate in the review queues.